# Change Nautilus file view

Tags: nautilus

In Nautilus you can view files as a list or as a grid. Both options take too much space on the screen and I am wondering if there is an even smaller list view that can be used to list my files without going to the cli and doing a >ls?

Comment: And you have already looked at 'list' view with less columns included OR shrinking the content (zoom)?

Comment: Ah yeah, if I just press ctrl + mousewheel to make it smaller, then that is better. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out what I wanted to do. If you open Nautilus, go to preferences at the top of the page, then change the default viewing zoom %, then it saves it there for everything you open. Now my view is miles better!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Nautilus:

[image]

and in the <kbd>View</kbd> drop-down menu, click <kbd>zoom out</kbd> or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>